# Send emails using CKEditor in HTML format

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

Im having problems sending emails in HTML format using the CKEditor. I have the latest one and installed on to my site. This is my simple contact form to test the software out but every time I insert a link or something in HTML, the output in the email is

my code is:

```
    <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ckeditor/sample.css">
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<html>
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" class="ckeditor"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
    </form> 
    <?php 
    }  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    { 
    $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
    $email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
    $message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
        } 
    else{         
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
        mail("email@example.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
        echo "Email sent!"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe the mail content-type is not HTML. In any case I'd suggest using a mail sending library, like SwiftMailer

Comment: Did you get the help you needed? What worked?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you need to add the right headers to the `mail()` function, other wise it will send plain text emails.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

them you can add the content to the email:

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Cool Email</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

them it should work.. good luck

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is straightforward; you need to specify email headers that indicate the message contains HTML: [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

See **Example #4**.

Specifically:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

And then to put it all together with your existing code:

```
$headers .= "\r\n" . $from;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

[How-To-Code-Html-Emails](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails)

It suggest to send your html email in Multipart/Alternative MIME

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would give the simple answer, as I have just spent forever figuring this out. Hope it helps someone out.

```
$send_to = $_POST['send_to']; 
$subject= $_POST['subject']; 
$body= $_POST['body']; 
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'From: Your name <your@email.com>';


$msg = '<html><body><head></head>';
$msg .= "Dear $first_name $last_name, \n$body"; 
$msg .= '</body></html>';

mail($email, $subject, $msg, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```